# Div with geolocation not showing on my website

Tags: javascript, html

I have an issue with a div I created with the standard geolocation API not showing on my website.
I am just fooling around a bit with HTML and JavaScript and I just can't get the latitude and longitude showing on my site. What am I doing wrong?

```html
<!-- Main page heading -->
<!-- Header 1 for showing the time -->
<div>
  <h1 class="header">
    <p id="date"></p>
    <script>
      let d = new Date();
      let h = d.getHours();
      let m = d.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
      document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "The current time is " + h + ":" + m + " "
    </script>
  </h1>
</div>

<!-- Header two for showing the location / Doesn't work yet -->
<div>
  <h2 class="header">
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
      var x = document.getElementById("demo");

      function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else {
          x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
      }

      function showPosition(position) {
        x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
          "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
      }
    </script>
  </h2>
</div>

<!-- Header three for random number / between 0 and 100 -->
<div>
  <h3 class="header">
    <p id="demo2"></p>
    <script>
      let y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
      let z = Math.round(y * 100) / 100;
      document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = z;
    </script>
  </h3>
</div>
```

The first div showing the current time is showing perfectly fine, the second one is not doing anything. The third one again is showing with a random number. Does anyone know what I need to change?

I tried different kinds of styles, but there is just no text showing. Also tried to add the script from div1 to div2, also nothing showing.

Comment: Did you just forget to call the `getLocation()` function anywhere?

Comment: That's not how the [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition)  works. If you use `console.log(location.geolocation)` you will see that your code always returns `undefined` unless you specifically allow the browser to track your geolocation

Comment: FYI: The Geolocation API only works when using `HTTPS`  (localhost should be fine though) - See the note in the website linked above

Comment: Consider only ONE `<script` tag not mulitple/3 like you demonstrate here.

Comment: I actually did forget to call the function anywhere.. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Just reading that tip now, how would I do that? Create a .js file and call that in the div? Would that then be multiple .js files )for every div one file) or can it be done by one?

Comment: Just move the code from one (probably the latter) to the other - OR better yet move it ALL to a .JS file. FWIW I am NOT a fan of globals like `var x = document.getElementById("demo");` which are both visible and overwritable to ALL the JavaScript on the page.  Better to namespace it at the very least.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some inspection i found out that `getLocation` is a function and you didn't call it.

You need to call the function.

This is how you are going to call it:

```html
<!-- Main page heading -->
<!-- Header 1 for showing the time -->
<div>
  <h1 class="header">
    <p id="date"></p>
    <script>
      let d = new Date();
      let h = d.getHours();
      let m = d.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
      document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "The current time is " + h + ":" + m + " "
    </script>
  </h1>
</div>

<!-- Header two for showing the location / Doesn't work yet -->
<div>
  <h2 class="header">
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
      var x = document.getElementById("demo");

      function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else {
          x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
      }

      function showPosition(position) {
        x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
          "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
      }
      getLocation()
    </script>
  </h2>
</div>

<!-- Header three for random number / between 0 and 100 -->
<div>
  <h3 class="header">
    <p id="demo2"></p>
    <script>
      let y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
      let z = Math.round(y * 100) / 100;
      document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = z;
    </script>
  </h3>
</div>
```

I have tested it and it is working

Comment: Thanks, seems to work for me too! Actually did forget to call the function..

Comment: You just copied comments thatw ere given as comment because of the nature of the issue. While it would be ok to post answers from someone else comments you miss the fundamental issues that still persist such as this code: `if (navigator.geolocation) { navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition); } else { x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser."; }` which did not work because the statement can never be false.

Comment: First of all I have answered the question from my self without reading the comments. And it can return false if you are using an old browser

Comment: No, it will not return false, it will return an `undefined` or `empty object`. That's why the documentation specifically allows the use of an error function. A false would be received if nothing would be returned which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object and store stuff in there; and use it right from there.  I also show how to put functions in it and call them but kept one outside (it might also be in there) and called it all in the self executing function `(function() {`.
NOTE: this secure feature has to be "allowed" re: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/geolocation

```js
(function() {
  var myThings = {
    setTime: function() {
      this.d = new Date();
      this.h = this.d.getHours();
      this.m = this.d.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
      document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "The current time is " + this.h + ":" + this.m;
    },
    setDemo2: function() {
      this.y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
      this.z = Math.round(this.y * 100) / 100;
      document.getElementById("demo2").textContent = this.z;
    },
    setPosition: function(position) {
      console.log('hi');
      const pc = position.coords;
      this.demo.textContent = "Latitude: " + pc.latitude +
        "<br/>Longitude: " + pc.longitude;
    }
  };
  myThings.setTime();
  myThings.setDemo2()

  function getLocation() {
    myThings.demo = document.getElementById("demo");
    myThings.demo.textContent = "Before";
    if ("geolocation" in window.navigator) {
      myThings.demo.textContent = 'hi 1';
      window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(myThings.setPosition);
    } else {
      myThings.demo.textContent = 'not me';
      myThings.demo.textContent = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
  }

  getLocation();
}());
```

```css
#demo,
#demo2 {
  border: solid 2px #ff0000;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="header">
    <p id="date"></p>
  </h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h2 class="header">
    <p id="demo"></p>
  </h2>
</div>
<div>
  <h3 class="header">
    <p id="demo2"></p>
  </h3>
</div>
<!--commented out but script COULD go here
<script>
 //put script here
</script>
-->
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am just a beginner, so sorry for the noobiness. And again, thanks for the time you spend on this!

Comment: Sure, this was a pretty easy refactor of your code; we all had to learn from the start so no need for an apology.  I see global variables getting created all the time even in large code bases where it is not uncommon to see more than one set of code use the same name which causes harder to debug issues when it can be in many places/files in the code.